# Solution method linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving for the equilibrium strategy in a first-price auction with common value. During the process of maximization of the utility function of a generic bidder I've encountered the following differential equation, but I'm not able even to guess a possible solution because I've never studied ODE.

Start from here:

$$ \pi= \int_{0}^{\omega}v + y- b(\omega)-b(\omega)+ydy$$

then

$$\frac{d \pi}{d \omega} = v + 2 \omega -2[b(\omega)+ \omega b'(\omega)]$$

My problem is to solve the following:

$$3v - 2b(v) - 2 vb'(v) = 0  $$

where $ b(\cdot)$ is a strictly increasing function and $b(0)$ need not to be equal to $0$. Does somebody can help me?

Comment: $\frac {d}{dv}bv = b + b'v.$  Isolate this expression, and then integrate both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hint***

$$3v - 2b(v) - 2 vb'(v) = 0$$
$$3v - 2(b +  vb') = 0$$
$$3v - 2(bv)' = 0$$
$$ (bv)'= \frac 3 2 v $$
Simply integrate :
$$ bv=\frac 3 2 \int vdv $$
For $v \neq 0 $
$$\boxed { b(v)=\frac 3 4 v+ \frac Kv}$$
Note that for $(v=0)$ we have $3v - 2b(v) - 2 vb'(v) =-2b(0) =0$ And $b(0)=0$